Get type of a variable in Lumerical?
When I use Lumerical, you can define variables as such:
x = 1;
x1 = '1';

However, multiple types exists such as: matrix, cell, struct, number, string, etc.
I can create each of them, but how can I get the type of this?
If I can get their type, then I can distinguish them.

Use isinstance to solve problem.

Are you sure Lumerical Script has function isinstance???

?What 's language? I thought it was Python.

Lumerical Script
